# Nginx proxy to application on localhost

Tags: nginx, sonarqube

I have an nginx webserver set up on port 80.
My (SonarQube) app runs on port 9000. When I request http://www.example.com/sonar/ I wish to be redirected to Sonar, so i added this to my nginx config:

```
location /sonar/ {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000/;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_read_timeout  1800;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

However, when i go to http://www.example.com/sonar/, every link on this page goes to http://www.example.com/ instead of http://www.example.com/sonar/. So stylesheets, css scripts and links are broken. How can i fix this? I tried `rewrite`, but I can't seem to get it working....

Comment: /sonar/ and /Sonar/ are in the same domain example.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `proxy_pass` line. In your case, it should be:

```
proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000;
```

But NOT:

```
proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
```

In `proxy_pass` directive, if you specify the URI which is `/` in your case, the matched URI `/sonar/` will be replaced as the specified one `/`.

Comment: It says Error 404: page not found, when I alter that line.

Comment: Can you try to access `http://www.example.com:9000/sonar/` to check if there's 404 error?

Comment: This was part of the problem, in combination with setting up the prefix path for sonarQube itself.